# Tomcat response time is increasing as concurrency is increased in apache bench

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, apachebench

When I am increasing concurrency `-c` in ab (apache bench) then I am getting different response time.

```
-c      99%
3       2ms
5       4ms
8       6ms
```

If I increase `-c` further then response time will increase as well.My code is extremely simple, No thread starvation, no blocking, etc. Then **why the response time is getting increased?**

I think that `ab -c 8` means 8 simultaneous request would be made to `http://localhost:8070/benchmark`. So **is it possible that requests are getting pooled at tomcat?** If it is so then **how can I make tomcat handle more concurrent users with less response time (4ms at 99%)?**

```
@RestController
public class PerformanceController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/benchmark",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRetargetingData(){
        return "Just plain call";
    }

}

ritesh@ritesh:~$ ab -n 10000 -c 3 'http://localhost:8070/benchmark'
Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8070

Document Path:          /benchmark
Document Length:        15 bytes

Concurrency Level:      3
Time taken for tests:   2.602 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4050000 bytes
HTML transferred:       150000 bytes
Requests per second:    3843.57 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       0.781 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.260 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1520.16 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:     0    1   0.5      1      23
Waiting:        0    1   0.4      1      23
Total:          0    1   0.5      1      24

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      1
  95%      1
  98%      2
  99%      2
 100%     24 (longest request)


ritesh@ritesh:~$ ab -n 10000 -c 6 'http://localhost:8070/benchmark'
Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8070

Document Path:          /benchmark
Document Length:        15 bytes

Concurrency Level:      6
Time taken for tests:   1.814 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4050000 bytes
HTML transferred:       150000 bytes
Requests per second:    5514.16 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.088 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.181 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2180.89 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       1
Processing:     0    1   0.9      1      22
Waiting:        0    1   0.8      1      22
Total:          0    1   0.9      1      22

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      2
  95%      2
  98%      3
  99%      4
 100%     22 (longest request)


ritesh@ritesh:~$ ab -n 10000 -c 8 'http://localhost:8070/benchmark'

Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8070

Document Path:          /benchmark
Document Length:        15 bytes

Concurrency Level:      8
Time taken for tests:   1.889 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4050000 bytes
HTML transferred:       150000 bytes
Requests per second:    5293.55 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.511 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.189 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2093.64 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       2
Processing:     0    1   1.8      1      50
Waiting:        0    1   1.8      1      50
Total:          0    1   1.8      1      50

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%      2
  95%      3
  98%      5
  99%      6
 100%     50 (longest request)
ritesh@ritesh:~$ ab -n 10000 -c 500 'http://localhost:8070/benchmark'
Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8070

Document Path:          /benchmark
Document Length:        15 bytes

Concurrency Level:      500
Time taken for tests:   1.830 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      4050000 bytes
HTML transferred:       150000 bytes
Requests per second:    5464.11 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       91.506 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.183 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2161.10 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   25 154.8      0    1001
Processing:     1   23  45.7     12     818
Waiting:        1   23  45.6     12     818
Total:          2   48 188.5     12    1818

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     12
  66%     17
  75%     22
  80%     26
  90%     45
  95%     66
  98%   1021
  99%   1220
 100%   1818 (longest request)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this test is telling you anything useful because you're not using an actual network connection. Your response times are going to increase substantially if you test between two different machines, to the extent that the difference between 2ms and 6ms will be just noise.

Comment: @SteveC: Thanks for pointing that out. But I am more curious about why response time is increasing even on same machine?

Comment: Well, you piqued my curiosity. So I tried a similar test myself, albeit using standard JAX-RS in WildFly 8.1.0.Final. (I can then test with a 2kB WAR file). Running on my MacBook Pro the 99% and under response times were 1ms or less, even at -c 16. I had to let the OS "rest" between tests otherwise it would start throttling. Therefore, any variation I found tended to be a consequence of OS level things going on.

Comment: @SteveC: My hardware is not good comparison to yours . So my -c number is less. But even if you do test on your machine then I hope that you will find ridiculously small number comparison to very plain vanilla code. Try to run -c 100. If I am not wrong tomcat can manage 200 concurrent users. (http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=How_to_optimize_tomcat_performance_in_production)